# Reopenprogram function returns type error "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have the following javascript code which should be able to create a dialog box triggered by an onclick event in the html file.
But strangely I alway get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. By the way the TypeError concerns the reopenprogram(element) function!!! I have already checked whether the element is really null but putting it in alert showed me the usual element name. I know the code looks a little bit rough but I am free for any suggestions. Here is the [jsfiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippB/yY93B/) I am pretty new to javascript so I would be really glad if you could fully adjust the code yourself.

Please help me!

```
function executeprogram(element) {

var program = document.createElement("div");
var toolbar = document.createElement("div");
var title = document.createElement("div");
var minimize = document.createElement("div");
var close = document.createElement("div");
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

// Create program Div //
program.id = element;
program.className = "dialog";
program.width = iframe.width;
add(element);
program.setAttribute("onmousedown", "dragstart(this)");
container.appendChild(program);

// Toolbar //

toolbar.id = "toolbar";
toolbar.width = iframe.width;
program.appendChild(toolbar);

// Title //

title.id = "title";
title.innerHTML = element;
toolbar.appendChild(title);

// Minimize //

minimize.id = "minimize";
minimize.innerHTML = "-";
minimize.onclick = minimizeprogram(element);
toolbar.appendChild(minimize);

// Close //

close.id = "close";
close.innerHTML = "x";
close.onclick = closeprogram(element);
toolbar.appendChild(close);

// Create Iframe //
iframe.frameBorder = 1;
iframe.width = "500px";
iframe.height = "250px";
iframe.id = "iframe";
iframe.src = "#";
program.appendChild(iframe);
}

// Minimize program //

function minimizeprogram(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "hidden"; 
}
function reopenprogram(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.visibility = "visible"; 
}

// Close program //

function closeprogram(element) {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var app = document.getElementById(element);

    container.removeChild(app);

    remove(element);
}

// Tabs //

function add(element) {
    var tabs = document.createElement("li");
    tabs.id = ""+element+"tab";
    alert(element);
    tabs.onclick = reopenprogram(element);

    var add = document.getElementById("tabs");  
    add.appendChild(tabs);
}
function remove(element) {
    var add = document.getElementById("tabs");
    var app = document.getElementById(element+"tab");
    add.removeChild(app);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, you never add an element with the id of the `element` argument value to the document. That is the cause.

Comment: I would if I knew where it should be added and how it should be created (you don't seem to even create this element in your code.)

Comment: The onclick event handler only creates a string variable with the value 'Calculator' passed into `executeprogram()`. JS code creates some elements (`var tabs = document.createElement("li");`) but they don't have matching ids. The HTML code doesn't have any id-matching elements, either.

Comment: I still don't get the problem! What's the problem with this code for instance?? document.getElementById(element).style.visibility = "visible";

Comment: In this statement, `element`'s value denotes the value of the `id` attribute of some element found in the document. Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById). You don't have such an element in the document's DOM tree, that's the problem.